# Ubuntu doesn't see Oracle JDK 8 however it is in the system

Tags: jdk, oracle

I have Ubuntu 15.10 (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-42-generic x86_64) on my server and trying to upgrade it to '16.04.6 LTS'.
After running the command:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f
```

I've got the next error:

```
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed
```

However:

```
 java -version
 java version "1.8.0_101"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

I have installed the update for JDK from an archive but it was not successful too.
How can I fix it?

Comment: I think it's `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: @Jim it warned me that this process through ssh can be dangerous.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8884/whats-the-risk-of-upgrading-over-ssh